# Query Posts, order by meta value

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, meta-query

I've read a lot, tried a lot more, but can't get what I want: I have custom post types, which I want to order in DESC, orderby its meta value:

The complete query with its arguments:

```
wp_reset_query();
$args = array(
            'meta_key'          => 'completeness',
            'order_by'          => 'meta_value_num',
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'order'             => 'DESC',
            'post_type'         => 'datensatz',
            'post_status'       => 'draft'
        );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query -> have_posts() ):
    while ( $the_query -> have_posts()) : 
        $the_query -> the_post();
        global $post;
        echo get_the_title().':'.get_post_meta( $post->ID, "completeness", TRUE ).'<br/>';
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

This query does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have just had a look at the last db query by `$wpdb->last_query` and got this:

```
 "SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (206,200,199,198,197,[..]) ORDER BY meta_id ASC"
```

So my WP query MUST be wrong...

Comment: Do you really need to get `draft`. I think it should be `publish`. Also, does your meta key `completeness` have only numbers?

Comment: @Robert hue Yep. I need to get the draft and completeness is a non decimal, numeric value.

Comment: It should be working. Nothing is wrong in it. Why don't you try it step by step and see where is the problem. First add only `post_type` then add `post_status`, and so on. Also post complete query.

Comment: @Robert hue I did it stepwise. Right now I am on the part with the meat query and it does not work. Have a look at my edit above, there you can see the whole query.

Comment: Why there're two `wp_reset_query();` there? Both are wrong by context. Use `wp_reset_postdata();` once, only after the `WP_Query()`, not before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems fine but there are couple of issues. Instead of your code (from `wp_reset_query();` to `wp_reset_query();`) use following code and let us know what is the output.

```
$new_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'datensatz',
    'post_status'       => 'draft',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'completeness',
    'orderby'          => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
);

$my_new_query = new WP_Query( $new_args );

var_dump( $my_new_query->request );
```

**EDIT**

Now try this. This should also work.

```
$new_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'datensatz',
    'post_status'       => 'draft',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'completeness',
    'orderby'          => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
);

$my_new_query = new WP_Query( $new_args );

if ( $my_new_query -> have_posts() ) :
    while ( $my_new_query -> have_posts()) : $my_new_query -> the_post();
        echo get_the_title() . ': ' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, "completeness", TRUE ). '<br/>';
    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: this is what I get: "SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'datensatz' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'draft')) AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'completeness' ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC "`

Comment: That's working perfectly. No problem in the query. I have made EDIT in my answer, use that instead. And let me know the result.

Comment: :Nope, this does not work, they are still not getting sorted by "completeness"....I#ve build a workaround: I write them all into anrray and sort it by subkey. Not the ebst solution but it works.

Comment: If you are getting posts from this query but not sorting is not correct then remove `order` parameter from above code or change it to `ASC`

Comment: I tried both but it fif not work.

Comment: Please explain what exactly not working and how you want it to display. `order` parameter only have 2 options. `ASC` - ascending order from lowest to highest values (1, 2, 3; a, b, c). and `DESC` - descending order from highest to lowest values (3, 2, 1; c, b, a).

Comment: It's just a typo - `orderby` not `order_by`!

Comment: Thanks @bonger, yes. How did I missed it. :D I updated above code with this correction.